# How do I reset gnome-shell-theme.gresource file?

Tags: gnome, themes

I was trying to change the colour of the lock screen changing some hex values. I changed the values and tried to see if it worked by locking my system. When I tried that, it was all messed up. I tried to reset GNOME, but when I did that it messed it up even more and now not only my lock screen is messed up but also my home screen is messed up.

This is how it looks:

[image: a pic of how its messed up]

How to fix this, or revert to the original?

Comment: Which files did you modify?

Comment: gnome-shell-theme.gresource

Comment: i probably deleted a line of code there

Comment: You can use [mine](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lJRHMMI6c6xb4bpydFfqQqc9bQIYymZ1/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @Jos Thank you very much dude that actually worked